# Schema design for accumulated data on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm searching and studing a lot how can i do this... I read many similar use cases, but i need some more complicated.

I will need collect this informations:

** Report Between April 2013 and Sept 2013 **

**1- Monthly not accumulated report:**

> group1: {
>        "04" : {"photos" : 1, "documents" : 2, "likes" : 0},
>        ...
>        "09" : {"photos" : 0, "documents" : 3, "likes" : 10}   },   group2: ...

My group1 had 1 photo, 2 documents and 0 likes this mounth(4).
  My group2 ...

**2- Monthly accumulated report:**

```
  group1: {
     "04" : {"photos" : 10, "documents" : 20, "likes" : 500},
     ...
     "09" : {"photos" : 100, "documents" : 200, "likes" : 3000}
  },
  group2: ...
```

My group1 has at total 10 photos, 20 documents and 500 likes since the group was created until end range of date search.

And i will have the daily not accumulated report and daily accumulated report too.

The accumulated reports is how much photos, documents and likes my group had this month/day, like a historical report.
The not accumulated reports is how much photos, documents and likes my group got only this month/day.

The many use cases that i saw, it's about page views, analytics like google... but anyone has the accumulated data...
Anyone know a better schema design for my situation?

Thanks,
Diego

Comment: The ideal schema design always depends on what queries you want to perform on the data. Why do you believe that what you have is insufficient? What problems did you encounter when you tried to do something with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got!

I created 3 colletions:

```
accumulated_stats: :_id, :photos, :documents

monthly_stats: :_id, date, :counts {:photos, :documents}, accumulated {:photos, :documents}

daily_stats: :_id, date, :counts {:photos, :documents}, accumulated {:photos, :documents}
```

Now, for each action, i will increment accumulated_stats, get the results and increment daily and monthly stats. it works as well!

But for showing the data.. i won't have all date time.. for instance:

```
2013-09-10
2013-09-11 ( do not have )
2013-09-12
2013-09-13
```

I'm looking for a way to construct the perfect date range. For instance, i don't have the day 11 on my collection, how can i bring it with the last existent values? any ideas?

Thanks,
Diego